# how get rid of transitive intra-project (i.e. modul to modul) dependency in SBT multi module project

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I have 3 modules (`jvm`,`stateAccess`, `persistence`), with the following dependency:

`jvm->stateAccess->persistence`.

I would like to isolate `jvm` from `persistence` completely, as if from the point of view of `jvm` `persistence` did not exist. So `jvm` should not be able to import anything from `persistence`.

However with the following `build.sbt` file, this is not the case:

```
lazy val jvm = (project in file( "jvm" ))
  .settings(...)
  .dependsOn( stateAccess % "compile->compile;test->test" )

lazy val persistence = (project in file( "persistence" ))
  .settings(...)

lazy val stateAccess = (project in file( "stateAccess" ))
  .settings(...)
  .dependsOn( persistence )
```

The problem is that `jvm` can see `persistence` .

It is due to a transitivity of the dependency relation in SBT: `jvm` can import classes from `persistence` and use them even though `jvm` does not depend directly on `persistence`.

In other words, I want to make sure that `jvm` only depends on `stateAccess` and cannot use anything from `persistence`.

Is there a way to forbid such transitive dependencies ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude transitive dependencies of other subproject in multiproject builds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035716/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependencies-of-other-subproject-in-multiproject-build)

Comment: No. That is about multi project, this is about multi module.

Comment: multi module : http://xerial.org/blog/2014/03/26/buidling-multi-module-projects-in-sbt/

Comment: Also that question talks about libraries. Here are no libraries. In addition to that here the transitivity is due to the dependencies defined inside the `build.sbt.` , in that question I don't even see where the transitivity might come from (it does not come from the build file that I can see). as in : `val coreLib = Projects.coreLib()
val consoleApp = Projects.consoleApp().dependsOn(coreLib)
val androidApp = Projects.androidProject().dependsOn(coreLib)` ... with these dependencies I don't see how transitivity even can arise.

Comment: If someone thinks that the other question answers this question then please show me how - because I don't see it.

Comment: My bad re the duplicate question. So, I hate to answer a question with a question, but can you define the difference between multimodule and multiproject? The post on Xerial you linked to doesn't clarify it.

Comment: In my understanding multi project is where there are multiple jars/classpaths/build.sbt etc involved, each project is a separate compilation entity. Here however, there is only one .jar/build.sbt but several modules (i.e. different locations of source files).

Comment: Here is https://pathtogeek.com/multi-project-builds-with-sbt-0-12-for-scala-project and https://pathtogeek.com/adding-scalastyle-in-a-multi-module-sbt-scala-project ... .

Comment: There might be some confusion here... that I admit....

Comment: Nevertheless, that other question does not answer this question. At least reading that I have no clue how to solve this question :( because the dependency structure is different and they are talking about dependencies on external projects (probably libraries) and here I am talking about dependencies between internal modules.

Comment: They talk about inter-project dependencies, I talk about intra-project dependencies. "What the projectDepenendencies is doing is what sbt, by default, attempts to do. It converts any inter-project dependencies into ModuleIDs which Ivy will use during resolution."

Comment: Try redefining the dependency between jvm and persistence to be only a runtime dependency. That might take it out of jvm's compile scope.

Comment: Could `exportJars` help you? http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Howto-Classpaths.html#Use+packaged+jars+on+classpaths+instead+of+class+directories

Comment: @DaleWijnand how ?

Comment: @JorgeVicenteCantero to me it seems that it just changes the format but not the logic... so i would expect the same behaviour.... if behaviour were different than that should have been documented there....

Answer (score -1):

```
lazy val stateAccess = (project in file( "stateAccess" ))
  .settings(...)
  .dependsOn( persistence  % "compile-internal;test-internal" )
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the answer to add some explanation as to why the proposed approach solves the problem?