# buildt.sbt: exclude dependencies from dependsOn submodule

Tags: scala, build, dependencies, sbt

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035716/how-to-exclude-transitive-dependencies-of-other-subproject-in-multiproject-build) but that solution does not work in sbt v1.x

In the build sbt it is well documented how to exclude dependencies when added through `libraryDependencies`:

```
libraryDependencies += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.15" exclude("javax.jms", "jms")
```

or preventing transitive dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.felix" % "org.apache.felix.framework" % "1.8.0" intransitive()
```

but my question is how (and if) it can be done when declaring `dependsOn` dependencies of submodules in a multi-module project like this:

```
lazy val core = project.dependsOn(util)
```

How would I do something like this (invalid code in example below) to prevent a transitive dependency from being brought in via `util`:

```
lazy val core = project.dependsOn(util exclude("javax.jms", "jms"))
```

also how, and more importantly, how to exclude a transitive dependency on another submodule in the multi-module project from being brought in via `util` (where `sub3` is another submodule project declared in the same build.sbt):

```
lazy val core = project.dependsOn(util exclude sub3)
```

Answer (score 7):

The way to do it, is to use `excludeDependencies` SettingKey.

An short example:

```
excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("commons-logging", "commons-logging")
)
```

[Source](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies)

---

If you happen to define your dependencies as `val` (as I do), you might find it useful to define the excludes based on your dependencies. To do so, you need this simple method:

```
def excl(m: ModuleID): InclExclRule = InclExclRule(m.organization, m.name)
```

and it allows for easy exclusions:

```
val theLib = "com.my.lib" % "artifact" % "version"

lazy val `projectA` = (project in file("projectA"))
  .settings(
    ...
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      theLib
    )
  )

lazy val `projectB` = (project in file("projectB"))
  .settings(
    ...
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
    ),
    excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
      excl(theLib)
    )
  )
  .dependsOn(projectA)
```

Comment: I believe `excludeDependencies` is only available in SBT >= 1.0

Comment: Because that is what was the question about

Comment: doh! indeed. sorry.